# No input file specified while using Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I just create a server recently, and use Nginx as my web server.

I did : `service nginx force-reload`

- Reloading nginx configuration nginx         [ OK ]

Then I do `service nginx status`

- nginx is running

Knowing that my site is running, but when I go to it. I see `No input file specified.` Wired ???

Here is what I have in my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /default/public;
```

Can someone please help me fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fix this problem by assign my document root to the **correct path** :

`root /home/forge/default/public;`

If you see `No input file specified.`, make sure you set your root to the correct path.

Comment: Yeah this happened to me, I cloned a vanilla site that didn't have the prefix of `/public` which Forge expects.